# Docker image with libraries + MLFlow Experiments

Tags: docker, databricks, mlflow

I have a scenario where we have multiple teams working with Python and R, and this teams uses a lot of different libraries.

Because of this dozen of libraries, the cluster start took much time. Then I created a Docker image, where I can install all the libraries that we need, for both Python and R.

It works fine, the cluster start isn't a problem anymore. But now, MLFlow experiment doesn't working any more, it saves data in a path like "/tmp/Rserv", and we can't see on the IU Experments anymore.

How can I do to have my libraries on this Docker image, but having access to the experiments on the UI on Databricks?

I tried to setup the following env variables:
ENV MLFLOW_HOME=/mlflow
WORKDIR $MLFLOW_HOME
EXPOSE 5000

But doesn't work.

Comment: Libraries are on the Docker image, but where is MLFlow server running?